# How to add IsRequired using FluentAPI under EF for .NET Core when pre-existing class lacks navigational fields?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

The background is that current DB is set up by the pains of thousand scripts and is to be regarded as untouchable. I'd like to shoot in a new table (which worked pretty OK [following this guide](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration#haswith-pattern#haswith-pattern#haswith-pattern#haswith-pattern)). However, I got stuck on creating relations to the pre-existing junk.

I have a new class declared as follows.

```
public class Stuff
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int OldThingId { get; set; }
  public virtual OldThing OldThing { get; set; }
}
```

I want it to have a parent of type *OldThing*, so I added the following.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  ...
  OnModelCreating(modelBuilder.Entity<Stuff>());
}
private void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeBuilder<Stuff> entity)
{
  entity.HasKey(a => a.Id);
  entity.HasOne(a => a.OldThing);
  //entity.HasOne(a => a.OldThing).IsRequired();
}
```

Here I'd like to use *WithMany* and *IsRequired* but since the old thing has no relation to the new stuff (and I prefer not to tamper with it), I'm not sure how to tell FluentApi that the field is required. The method seems not to exist on *HasOne*, regrettably.

How should I approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call `IsRequired()` on the `PropertyBuilder` on the `EntityTypeBuilder`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{        
    modelBuilder.Entity<Stuff>().HasKey(a => a.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Stuff>().HasOne(a => a.OldThing);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Stuff>()
        .Property(s => s.OldThingId)
        .IsRequired();
}
```